# Question regarding setup of Text Message Marketing Spams - Where is it most appropriate?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, asking-questions, scope

I asked a question with regard to the setup of text message spams [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/254340/caller-id-spoof-and-text-spams-how-do-they-work), which was knocked back as being too off-topic. I  [also asked it on Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6698/debt-settlement-order-text-spams-how-do-they-work), but really was wanting an answer from a technical setup perpective with regard to hardware/software setup,etc. To this end, I suspect this is also not the right place.

Would I get away with this on Stackoverflow? Or is there anywhere else that would be more appropraite?

Much appreciated,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is way to broad.  In fact you have a root desire to learn more that leads you to a list of questions that some of which could be asked on StackOverflow, SuperUser or ServerFault.

I suggest breaking up your set of questions into individual question posts and post to the most appropriate website.   However, some of your questions are just general questions about that industry that don't belong on any of these three and might not really belong on any SE site.

Comment: You're possibly right. My main problem is that I'm not 100% sure how excatly to ask these individually. I'll probably try some more reaseach myself and come back when I'm in a better position to do so. Although, what comes first, the StackExchangeChicken, or MyUnderstandingEgg? :-) Thanks.

Comment: You can give a lot of the same background in each question, but focus on asking just about hardware, or just about programatically handling text replies, etc.